# ANR: Executing service InvisibleToUser

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

In the Play Console, we're getting the following Application Not Responding error: `executing service com.example.com/.NotificationListener, InvisibleToUser`.

The interesting thing is that this is only happening on Motorola devices so far.

I couldn't find any information on this particular part of the error, `invisibleToUser`. Does it simply mean that the ANR error wasn't visible to the user, in the UI? Can anyone give some explanation or pointers to where I can find more information?

Comment: I have the same problem. Still finding a fix. Did you found a fix?

Comment: Anyone make any progress on this?

Comment: Same here. Only Motorola devices :|